# event click in header of section of accordion

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-accordion

it's there a way to add an event click to a header of accordion, i tried using this selector but it doesn't work

```
$("#accordion :h3").click(function () {

    if ($("#tblCheck").is(':hidden'))
        $("#tblCheck").fadeIn('slow');
    else
        $("#tblCheck").hide();

});
```

**also i tried like this**

```
$("#accordion h3")
```

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The accordion is probably created after you try to bind the event, so you could use `.live()`:

```
$("#accordion h3").live('click', function() {
    ...
});
```

That should do it.